# Add same items in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qtreewidget

I have 2 QTreeWidgets (treeWidget_rigResults, treeWidget_migrateAnm) in my UI, similar but with different number of columns.

Anyway, I realized that while I am able to add my selection from `treeWidget_rigResults` into `treeWidget_migrateAnm`, I am only to add the same item once.

Are there any other ways in which I can add it more than once?
I have presented a screenshot here, where the "Name" under the Search Filter will be of the same value as the "Name" in the Migrate section

Not sure if this helps, but this is the code portion in which I did for the pushbutton "Add Rig" from `treeWidget_rigResults` into `treeWidget_migrateAnm`

```
selected_items = self.ui.treeWidget_rigResults.selectedItems()
root_item = self.ui.treeWidget_migrateAnm.invisibleRootItem()
for item in selected_items:
    if not self.ui.treeWidget_migrateAnm.findItems(item.text(0), QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly, 0):
        source_name = item.text(0)

        tree_item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(root_item)
        tree_item.setText(0, source_name)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been busy with the QTreeWidget as well.
To add a the same item in again you just need to make sure you don't overwrite the entry's id number ( 0, 1, 2, etc)

Example:

```
for v, i in enumerate(list):

        entry = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(i)
        [tree widget name].insertTopLevelItem(v, entry )
```

The "v" gives each entry its own id number, this allows for more than one of each name

Comment: Actually I have managed to rectify the issue, turns out within my code, I am hardcoding to add in a single item of the same naming. After much tweaking, I am able to add more than an item of the same name. Thanks again!